# Error 22007 in postsql 14 stored procedure parameter: invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: c#, postgresql, timestamp

I'm having an issue calling a PostgreSQL 14 insert stored procedure from C#.
I’m reading in an excel spreadsheet and Column U contains a value of Sep 27, 2021 06:59:33 EDT. I need to Insert this value to my postgresql db. I’m not interested in the EDT, in fact, I don’t even need the time. I am able to change the table structure however I want, but right now this column is defined as a timestamp without time zone.

Code:

```
NpgsqlConnection myConn = new NpgsqlConnection(pgsqlconnectionstring);
myConn.Open();
string callsp = “Call public.mysproc(‘cola’,’colb’….’first_discovered’,…)"
NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(callsp, myConn);

//…
Switch (column)
//…
Case “U”
  DateTime testdate;
  string trimmeddate = currentcellvalue.Substring(0, currentcellvalue.LastIndexOf(" "));
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(trimmeddate, "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out testdate))
     {
        pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("first_discovered", testdate);
                 //Value of testdate = {9/27/2021 6:59:33 AM}
     }
          break;

    Pgcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here I get an exception ex = {"22007: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "first_discovered"\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 167"}

I've tried various formats, dates, timestamps etc - none seem to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what `pgcom` is referring to, but it is obvious you are passing the string "first_discovered" to a `timestamp` field.

Comment: no, the first parameter of AddWithValue is the parameterName, and "first_discovered" is the parameterName. If I look in the QuickWatch window the value is populated correctly in the parameter... Thanks for answering tho.

Comment: Yet the error message says `...invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "first_discovered"...`. So "first_discovered" is being passed in as the value for the field per: `select 'first_discovered'::timestamp; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "first_discovered"`.  The message is telling you what the problem is. Somewhere what you think is happening is not what is actually happening. You need to step through your code and find where the mix up is.

Comment: The parameter itself is being correctly populated. It only fails when it's trying to execute pgcom (NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(callsp, myConn); I'm not sure how to paste a screenshot, but the QuickWatch of the parameter shows the NpgsqldbType = Timestamp, ParameterName = "first_discovered" and the NpgsqlValue = {9/27/2021 6:59:33 AM}

Comment: Believe the error message. To verify look at the Postgres log, I'm betting the value is "first_discovered". I don't use `Npgsql` but I  bet : `Call public.mysproc(‘cola’,’colb’….’first_discovered’,…)` is not doing what you think and `’first_discovered’` is not actually acting as placeholder for the parameter `first_discovered` but is instead just being passed in as the string "first_discovered".

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be found here [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) under **Positional and named placeholders**.